# Bundler causing capistrano deployment failure on a Rails 2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I have a Rails 2 app that a friend (and way better rails dev) helped me update with Bundler so that gem dependencies were better handled.

Now I am trying to deploy the app and capistrano is failing.

https://gist.github.com/1383514

that gist is the relevant log output from my capistrano deploy.

I am requiring:
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

in my deploy.rb file

It seems to me that the issue is that capistrano can't touch the gemfile because it doesn't exist.

Any one have a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is `bundle: command not found`

You'll have to `gem install bundler` or `sudo gem install bundler` on your server.

Comment: Thanks for the response UnixM... I have done that, and it shows up if I run gem list.  However if I run bundle from any directory, it says: Could not locate Gemfile.

Comment: @TJSherrill you need to run bundle from the rails app's root directory, where the Gemfile should be. If there is no Gemfile there, then you need to push it (and the Gemfile.lock) there. Make sure you commit them to your SCM repo.

Comment: I think I get that, the only question I have from here, is that on deployment, rails is creating a new folder in /releases so the root app folder on the production server is changed everytime I deploy... thoughts?

Comment: @TJSherrill Doesn't matter; capistrano already changes directory into that folder before running a command (a shown in your gist). Cap also gives you a 'current_path' variable that you can use for custom commands.

Comment: So, if I hear your right (kinda a rails noob here) I need to do one of two things: 1, use the current_path variable to copy my local gemfile and gemfile.lock to the prod server, or 2, ftp or ssh the files into the /current/ folder that is symlinked on the prod server?

Comment: @TJSherrill Your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock should be in your SCM (git/svn) repository. When you do 'cap deploy' that file should be checked out on the server automatically (because it's in your SCM). Maybe you could gist your deploy.rb if you are still having trouble.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1384042 is my deploy.rb, and my production.rb https://gist.github.com/1384046, so I run cap production deploy to deploy.  The gemfile and gemfile.lock are in my github repo so thats is working... I even tried manually copying the gemfiles to the shared/bundle/ path... no luck still

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5211/discussion-between-unixmonkey-and-tj-sherrill)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RVM on the server? I remember there is some additional setup to get Capistrano to use RVM.

**edit** See here: http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/